# Dictionary<T,List<U>> extension thread-safe method 'AddToList' that create a list if it does not exist

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I want to create an extension method like this :

```
public static void AddToList<T,U>(this Dictionary<T,List<U>> dictionary, T key, U value)
{
    // If the list exist, add to the list.
    // Else Create the list and add the item.
}
```

This is what I tried so far :

```
public static void AddToList<T,U>(this Dictionary<T,List<U>> dictionary, T key, U value)
{
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key) || dictionary[key] == null)
    {
        dictionary[key] = new List<U>();
    }
    dictionary[key].Add(value);
}
```

How could I handle thread safety with this method?

Comment: To lock the access in the dico so around the call of AddList

Answer (score 3):

If you need thread safety, you can use a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead.

```
var dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<T, List<U>>();
List<U> values = dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, _ => new List<U>());
```

Some additional notes:

1. Use `TryGetValue` instead of `GetOrAdd` to avoid creating an unnecessary `List<U>` if you are not in a method that will add a value to the list.
2. This only addresses the thread-safety concern of creating the `List<U>`. You still need to address operations on the individual lists.

Answer (score 0):

I would start using a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` which takes care of the thread-safety of adding non-existing lists in to dictionary.

Please note that you are always adding the item to the list, and you are not checking if the item is already in the list. If you want that, then that is another extra step to guarantee thread-safety.

```
public static void AddToList<T, U>(
    this ConcurrentDictionary<T, List<U>> dictionary,
    T key,
    U value
) {
    var list = dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, k => new List<U>());
    list.Add(value);
}
```

Comment: You're now adding items to a common list from multiple threads, which won't be safe.